# API to get mean and standard deviation for TFLite Models

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

How can we get these values of mean and standard deviation for any TFLite model ? Is there any API to fetch mean and std deviation ? where is this information stored ?

How can TFLite users know with what values they have to normalize the input ?
Can these values obtained run time ?

To change these mean and standard deviation ? what is the place to change , training ? (or) conversion (or) Inference ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the quantization parameters (mean and std to convert float to int), see https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/java/org/tensorflow/lite/Tensor.QuantizationParams (this is Java. similar API can be found for Python and C++)

If you're talking about mean / std to normalize input, TFLite core doesn't store that data. You can leverage TFLite Model Metadata (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/overview). But please note that it's optional for a TFLite model. We do encourage you attach your metadata if you're a model author.